# How to remove the line under the heading in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using the `Word` in the latest `Office 365`. I do not know which action I have done. The `Heading 1` always contains a line under the title, which is not `Underline`. So how to remove it?

[image]

---

I got it, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First double click the heading. Then go to Home tab > Borders button > Borders and shading. Now click None in "Setting" group and select Paragraph from "Apply to" list in the right-most pane. Then click OK.

Hope that helps

Borders button: [image]

Comment: Sorry, can you use screenshot to show me the "Borders button"?

Comment: Last button in the second line of Borders group

Comment: Also see the screenshot